# Do any Pokémon lose the ability to learn a HM when they evolve?

Tags: pokemon-fifth-generation, pokemon-series, pokemon-fourth-generation

Some Pokémon lose the ability to learn certain moves when they evolve. For example:

- Pichu learns Nasty Plot at level 18, but Pikachu can't learn or re-learn it
- Pichu can be taught Uproar by the Move Tutor, but Pikachu can't

In fourth or fifth generation of Pokémon games (Diamond/Pearl onward), are there any Pokémon who can learn a HM, but lose the ability to learn that HM when they evolve?

Comment: Without hard data, I don't think so. It's not uncommon for lower evolved forms (especially "baby" forms) to learn moves that later evolutions can't learn (especially when evolved via evolution stone), not familiar with any losing HMs though, since they're generally based on what it *looks* like the pokemon can do (swim, cut etc)

Comment: Although none of the Bug/Flying type Pokemon can learn Fly. In fact, the only Bug Pokemon that can learn Fly is the new legendary: Genesect. And Genesect doesn't have a secondary Flying type. Or really any apparent method of flight. -_-;;

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looking through the Bulbapedia learnset entries for each HM move, I have found no instances within each HM set where a Pokemon learn it, but its evolution can not;

1. [Cut](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Cut_%28move%29#By_HM) (HM01)

   - [Diglett/Dugtrio](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Diglett_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29/Generation_I_learnset#By_TM.2FHM) can learn Cut in Yellow, but not in R/B
2. [Fly](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Fly_%28move%29#By_HM) (HM02)*
3. [Surf](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Surf_%28move%29#Learnset) (HM03)*
4. [Strength](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Strength_%28move%29) (HM04)
5. [Flash](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Flash_%28move%29#By_HM.2FTM) (HM05 Gen 1-3)

   - [Venonat/Venomoth](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Venonat_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29/Generation_I_learnset#By_TM.2FHM) can to learn Flash in Yellow, but not in R/B. Venonat loses the ability to learn flash in Gen 2
   - [Hoothoot/Noctowl](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Hoothoot_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29/Generation_III_learnset#By_TM.2FHM) lose the ability to learn Flash in Gen 4, although it's no longer an HM.
6. [Defog](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Defog_%28move%29#Learnset) (HM05 D/P/Pt)
7. [Whirlpool](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Whirlpool_%28move%29#Learnset) (HM05 Hg/Ss - HM06 Gen 2)
8. [Waterfall](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Waterfall_%28move%29#Learnset) (HM05 Gen 5 - HM07 Gen 2-4)
9. [Rock Smash](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Rock_Smash_%28move%29#Learnset) (HM06 Gen 3-4)
10. [Dive](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Dive_%28move%29#Learnset) (HM06 Gen 5 - HM08 Gen 3)
11. [Rock Climb](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Rock_Climb_%28move%29#Learnset) (HM08 Gen 4)

There are a few fringe cases that pop up in earlier generations (Mostly between Red Blue and Yellow) where a Pokemon might learn the HM in one game and then be traded to another where its evolution cannot. There may also be unmentioned cases of this between Gens 1 and 2, however the [Time Capsule](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Time_Capsule) was fairly restrictive in what could be sent back.

*[Pikachu](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pikachu#By_events) is an interesting side case - As there are event and side-game transfers that can give you a Pikachu with Fly, or even Surf (there's also a surfing Pichu). However in none of these instances can Pikachu be taught the moves from an HM.

Comment: How does a Pikachu with Fly even work? O.o

Comment: @RavenDreamer I've narrowed it down to either falling with style, or [balloons](http://www.pokemontradingcards.net/images/pikachu-flying.jpg).

Comment: The official version is balloons. Surfing and Flying Pikachu are event-only jokes anyway...